# Unique slug from the same title in octobercms

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I am saving form inputs to the database with slug from the post's title this way

```
 $post = new Post();
       $post->title = Input::get('title');
       $post->slug = str_slug(Input::get('title'));
       ...
```

When two users enter exactly the same title for example "It is a new day", it generates the same slug "it-is-a-new-day" and the two posts clash. How can i fix this? Have not found a straight forward way that works yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If adding id is acceptable you could just save it and then update

```
$post= new Post();
$post->title = Input::get('title');
// you don't set slug here
// ...
$post->save();

$post->update(['slug' => str_slug($post->title).'-'.$post->id]);
```

and if line with `update` doesn't work (probably because of fillable), you should use:

```
$post->slug = str_slug($post->title).'-'.$post->id; 
$post->save();
```

instead of this line.

Comment: Tried it exactly. That did not work for me. Thought to have it how stackoverflow have it. ````https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59590580/unique-slug-from-the-same-title-in-octobercms````. so i tried ````$post->update(['slug' => str_slug($post->id).'/'.$post->title]);```` too but did not work

Comment: @KingsleyOsuji When you say it didn't work, you got any error?

Comment: It is saving without slug @Marcin

Comment: @KingsleyOsuji Not possible. It should save first without slug and then it should update the slug or throw exception is something is wrong. You can try with: `$post->slug => str_slug($post->title).'-'.$post->id; $post->save();` instead of using line with `update`

Comment: Ok. this works. thanks. just had to replace ````=>```` with ````=```` to make it work with octobercms